# how to add additional field in joomla 3 and 2.5?

Tags: joomla2.5

How can i add additional field in the Joomla 3 and 2.5 article administrator page
like this:
http://www.kavdesign.net/blog/coding/how-to-add-additional-field-in-the-joomla-article-administrator-page/

Where is the location of the following items in joomla 2.5 and 3
Files needed to edit:

```
jos_content table in joomla database
root/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php
root/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/form.php
root/administrator/components/com_content/models/article.xml
root/administrator/components/admin.content.html.php
root/administrator/components/config.xml
root/libraries/joomla/database/table/content.php
```

Answer (score 0):

This official joomla tutorial has all the information you need: [Adding custom fields to the article component](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component).

It also have an installation file to start with (section "Extension Files").

Good Luck!

Comment: Where is the location of the following items in joomla 2.5 and 3 Files needed to edit:

   jos_content table in joomla database
   root/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php
   root/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/form.php
   root/administrator/components/com_content/models/article.xml
   root/administrator/components/admin.content.html.php
   root/administrator/components/config.xml
   root/libraries/joomla/database/table/content.php

Comment: What you mean where is the location, you already have the paths. you just have to connect via ftp to your site and edit the appropriate files.

Comment: for example the following items is not in joomla 2.5 and 3:
root/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/form.php 
root/administrator/components/com_content/models/article.xml

Comment: The tutorial that you are trying to use is outdated, it's for joomla 1.5. Please try to use the link from my answer.